# EF recursing from Child to Parent?

Tags: entity-framework, recursion, tree

Is there any way I can get a chain of entities from EF that represents a chain from a Child all the way up to the root Parent entity in a self-referencing hierarchy?  I could of course do this with a while loop, such as:

```
var chain = new List<Node>();
var thisNode = db.Nodes.First(n => n.Id == [whatever]);
do {
    chain.Add(thisNode);
    thisNode = thisNode.ParentId == null ? null : thisNode.Parent;
} while (thisNode != null);
```

But I think this would result in one query to the DB for each level in the hierarchy.  While we're talking about an admittedly small performance gain here, is there a way I can express this logic as a single LINQ query to get the whole chain of companies from a given child all the way up to a parent where the parent meets a particular condition?  Or do I need to use a loop like this?

Comment: No, as asked and answered many times before, LINQ doesn't have any tooling for hierarchical queries. But you can load all data at once and rely on relationship fixup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837737/861716

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit of a "cheat" answer, but I actually achieved what I wanted with the awesome [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/).  I guess behind-the-scenes, it's doing the recursive work for me.  My EF entity has a `Parent` navigation property, my DTO to map to looks a little like this:

```
public class CompanyInChainDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CompanyInChainDTO Parent { get; set; }
}
```

... and this code causes AutoMapper to create a DTO chain from the child with the given ID up to the root parent (ie. the one with no `Parent`):

```
Mapper.Initialize(conf =>
{
    conf.CreateMap<EF.Company, CompanyInChainDTO>().MaxDepth(100);
});

using (var context = new EfContext())
{
    var child = context.Companies.First(comp => comp.Id == [whatever]);

    CompanyInChainDTO childDto = Mapper.Map<CompanyInChainDTO>(child);

    return childDto;  // Returns the child DTO with full Child -> Parent chain!
}
```

Very cool - I didn't know AutoMapper followed EF navigation properties by default.  Notice how I also use `MaxDepth(100)` for safety to prevent infinite recursion just in case there is no root parent company!

Comment: It surely simplifies the code, but it conceals the fact that still n + 1 queries are fired.

Comment: True, but I'm not sure there's any more efficient way to do it with EF.

Comment: No, indeed there isn't. If you want to extract one branch of an entire hierarchy you need SQL views based on hierarchical queries using CTEs.