# how To Write a Query That Get Each Entity With Sub Entities When We Have a Self-Relation Entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, ef-core-2.2

I using Ef Core 2.2.and I have an Entity It has Self-Relation And Each Entity Might have a List Of Entities

**This Is My Entity**

```
   public class CourseGroup
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        //Foreign key
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        //Navigations Property
        public CourseGroup ParentCourseGroup { get; set; }

        //Relatons => Self Relation
        public ICollection<CourseGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

**And This Is My Configurations**

```
 class CourseGroupConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CourseGroup>
    {
        public void Configure(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder<CourseGroup> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.Id);
            builder.Property(c => c.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(c => c.Title).HasMaxLength(60);

            //Relations
            builder.HasOne(c => c.ParentCourseGroup).WithMany(c => c.Groups).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
        }
    }
```

**And I Wanna get All Entities With Sub Entities. How Can I Write This Query With Linq?**
**Please Do me a favor to Write This Query**

Comment: `db.Set<CourseGroup>().ToList()`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827918/loading-a-full-hierarchy-from-a-self-referencing-table-with-entityframework-core/41837737#41837737

Comment: Or `db.Set<CourseGroup>().Include(cg => cg.Groups).ToList()`?

Comment: no.Query Result must be Something Like this
Each Entity may have a list of Entities
1.WebProgramming
           .AspCore
           .NodeJs
2.MobileProgramming
         .React naitive
         .xamarin

Comment: So what do these snippets of code not give you that you need?

Comment: First I didn't see your comment. I should try it to see if it works or not. thank u for your answer