# Nested include Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, include, subquery

I'm using EF Core for my project. And I have a problem with nested query in EF Core.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PermissionDefinitionEntity> PermissionDefinitions { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionDefinitionEntity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }

    public virtual PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PermissionDefinitionEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the ApplicationDbContext:

```
        builder.Entity<PermissionDefinitionEntity>().HasOne(r => r.Group).WithMany(r => r.PermissionDefinitions).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.Entity<PermissionDefinitionEntity>().HasOne(r => r.Parent).WithMany(r => r.Children).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I want query all `PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity` included `PermissionDefinitionEntity` and self referencing of `PermissionDefinitionEntity`.

Can I do that with EF Core?

Comment: You can't, at least not in one LINQ statement. This is a tree expansion of unknown depth, which requires recursive querying. Or if you want the whole tree, just query all `PermissionGroupDefinition`s and `PermissionDefinition`s (remove this redundant `Entity` suffix), which will populate all navigation properties.

Comment: So, I must be use recursive querying? Thanks for you support.

Comment: But can you explain about how can i get  the whole tree? I don't understand why remove Entity suffix? I think it just class name. @gert-arnold

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837737/861716. Removing the suffix is just an advice, it's useless and it reduces readability.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think i'll use  recursive querying for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recursively load `PermissionDefinitions` that placed in the `PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity`.

First, you should load all `PermissionGroupDefinitionEntities` including its children using the following query :

```
var query = _dbContext.PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(p => p.PermissionDefinitions )
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Children)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Since every `PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity` has a list of `PermissionDefinition` you need a nested loops like this code :

```
foreach (var PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity in PermissionGroupDefinitionEntities)
{
    foreach (var PermissionDefinitions in PermissionDefinitions)
    {

    }
}
```

Then in the inner loop you should call your recursive function.

See following link (sample for get all children recursively in Entity Framework Core)

https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-load-hierarchical-structure-with-recursive-with-entity-framework-5

This way has terrible performance and I don't recommend that.

In this case it's seems you must write a stored procedure in SQL for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.ThenInclude(i => ...)` like so

```cs
var query = _context.PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Include(i => i.PermissionDefinitions)
      .ThenInclude(i => i.Group)
  .AsQueryable();
```

Edit:

```cs
var query = _context.PermissionGroupDefinitionEntity
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Include(i => i.PermissionDefinitions)
      .ThenInclude(i => i.Children)
  .AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But when i use this query. I received error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Include path 'PermissionDefinitions->Group' results in a cycle. Cycles are not allowed in no-tracking queries; either use a tracking query or remove the cycle.'. And when i remove AsNoTracking. This query return only first level of PermissionDefinitions.

Comment: Oh I think I misread the question, I've edited my answer so can you try and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank for your support. This query return maximum two-level of PermissionDefinition. As PermissionGroupDefinition => PermissionDefinition => PermissionDefinition. If i have struct PermissionGroupDefinition => PermissionDefinition => PermissionDefinition => PermissionDefinition it not working.