# Entity Framework Core : self-referenced table not returning multiple levels

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using following to retrieve multiple levels of categories:

```
.Entity()
.HasOne(x => x.Manager)
.WithMany(x => x.Employees)
.ForeignKey(x => x.ManagerId)
```

However it is working with single level only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827918/loading-a-full-hierarchy-from-a-self-referencing-table-with-entityframework-core

Comment: So, you have hierarchical relationships. There are several ways to model hierarchies in relational databases. Namely, the 4 main ones and their varieties. You have chosen the so-called _adjacency list_. Recursive queries are needed to work with it. In pure SQL, they are done using CTE. Entity Framework is not able to make such queries. Look at the [LINQ to DB](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/CTE.html) ORM, it allows you to use CTE. Or use the [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) extension.